# Editing the registry - batch or C?

Tags: c++, c, windows, batch-file, registry

I want to write a tool that installs a few programs automatically after setting up a new system (that means copying the files and setting environment variables in the registry). The question is: Should I write a C program or "just" a batch script? What are the (dis-)advantages of both? Or should I even use a complete different language?

Comment: if you don't need context-dependent values just use a .reg file.

Comment: I use a bat file to perform various configuration tasks, write to the registry, copy files, and launch install packages. See REG ADD /?. Be sure to add error checking because sooner or later you will encounter an error (permissions, etc).